# Импорт фала из другого пакета

Tags: java, файлы, javafx, файловая-система

Повсюду можно найти лекции о том, как импортировать класс. Как импортировать файл?
Мой пример:

```
    public class JavaApplication36 extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Все хорошо");
        Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/scene1.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Адресная книга");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если начинаю писать *import*, то просто подчеркивает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне понятно, вы хотите загрузить файл `scene1.fxml` для дальнейшего использования.

В Java это делается при помощи методов `getResource()` или `getResourceAsStream()`,
со вторым возникает меньше проблем при запуске вне среды разработки.

В вашем случае нужно просто указать *полный* пакетный путь к вашему файлу:

```
public class JavaApplication36 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Все хорошо");
            Parent pane = FXMLLoader.load(JavaApplication36.class.getResource("Пакеты исходных кодов/fxml/scene1.fxml"));
                                                                               ^
                                                                               использовать кириллицу в названиях нехорошо
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 700, 500);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Адресная книга");
            primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Данный код не проверялся, но я почти уверен что он заработает

P.S кодовое слово `import` используется *только* для доступа с классам, интерфейсам и перечислениям (enum), но никак не к чему другому.

Comment: спасибо) еще один решение было: (../fxml/scene1.fxml)

Comment: @michael_best Пожалуйста, тоже подумал так, но этот способ может вызвать непонятные проблемы при запуске скомпилированного файла... а может и не вызвать, это как повезёт (до сих пор не понимаю до конца эти дьявольские методы :) )

Comment: @Jiftoo Ну в одном случае путь будет строиться от корня проекта, в другом от JavaApplication36.class.

Comment: @Maxim Вы правы, но этот способ не пригоден, если искомый файл будет находиться выше чем на один пакет вверх.

Comment: @Jiftoo Я за частую создаю пустой интерфейс-маркер (если ничего подходящего в пакете нет), который сразу меня направит на нужную ресурсную папку. Останется только добавить имя и не заботится о этих переходах вверх/вниз

Comment: @Maxim Интересное решение